# jquery autocomplete input - stop updating

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I just started using jquery (and autocomplete plugin) and all working ok

heres my scenario
I have a span element which I updates when user chooses one of the list values from autocomplete and it updates the input element at the same time. I dont want the autocomplete input element to be updated - I want to keep it with what user entered into it.

thanks in advance

regards

pvee

Comment: It depends on which autocomplete plugin your using (there are several).  Are you using the one that comes with jquery-ui?  Or some other.  Please add a link to their documentation or the site you downloaded your plugin from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQueryUI Autocomplete (in the future, please link to the plugin you're using), you can tap into the `select` event and use `event.preventDefault` to cancel the default behavior of the plugin (which is to replace the input text), and perform some other action:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault(); // cancel the default behavior of selecting an option
        $("#update-me").text(ui.item.label); // update the span with the selected option's label.
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5jWkL/

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks guys!!.. its jQueryUI autocomplete...
(my mistake, didnt mention what plugin I am using, mentioned that I just started jquery, and web programming)